# Jquery Plugin don't work with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using a marquee plugin in one of my page to provide news update, although this work when tested on normal browsers, when I compile and test on my phone, it does not work.

I am building a mobile apps using jquery mobile and phonegap.

I am using this plugin the at http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin

I have check for errors reports using Firefox web console and there was no error so to say.

Is there something I need to change?

Comment: We can't troubleshoot code if you don't post any.

Comment: It just a single line of code to start the ticker. I am sensing it is compatible with Jquery Mobile or something

Comment: Check for errors in the phone's console (chrome's device inspect for example).

Comment: I have checked time and time again, but there was no error.